# Deploying and executing programs on distributed remote machines

Tags: linux, deployment, distributed

I am developing a distributed program that will run on Amazon EC2 machines.

Ideally I would develop on my local machine, trigger a script to deploy the source on the remote machines (*All Linux machines on which I have ssh access*), trigger a compile command on each of the remote machines and then run the program on each instance while having control over the running programs (*being able to suspend them*).

I am wondering if there exist already any tools for such a task (except using MPI, but this is for another question), and if not, what best practices should I follow.

Answer (score 2):

There are many alternatives depending on your scale of deployment. An interesting one that I have not tried personally is [glu](https://github.com/linkedin/glu/wiki). There are also the well known puppet, chef family of config management tools that have some process control components.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you write Perl?

[Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aParallel) allows to write scripts that run commands in several servers in parallel via SSH quite easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::OpenSSH::Parallel;

my @hosts = (...);

my $pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new;
$pssh->add_host($_) for @hosts;

$pssh->all(rsync_put => '/local/path', '/server/path');
$pssh->all(cmd => 'cd /server/path && make');
$pssh->all(join => '*'); # waits for all the servers to reach this point.
$pssh->all(cmd => 'cd /server/path && ./your_program');

$pssh->run;
```